# Búsqueda de documentos con fecha en String

Tags: android, nodejs, mongoose, mongodb

Debido aun problema de compatibilidad de fechas entre Android y Mongoose se guardaron la fecha en un String en el formato **YYYY-MM-DD**, pero desearia hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
var dateNow = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var hourNow = moment().hours();
Activity.update({status:1, date:{$lt:dateNow}, hour:{$lt:hourNow}},{status:2},{multi:true},function(err){
 if(err){
   console.log(err);
   res.status(500).send(err);
 }
 res.status(200).send('Update');
});
```

El problema es que la funcion de mongo **$lt** al parecer no funciona con String.

En el peor de los casos no tengo ningún problema de cambiar de regreso el tipo de datos Date de mongoose, pero en php y mysql podía hacer consultas de este estilo.

Answer (score 2):

> Debido aun problema de compatibilidad de fechas entre Android y Mongoose se guardaron la fecha en un String en el formato `YYYY-MM-DD`

Ningún problema de compatibilidad te dificulta guardar una fecha en un modelo de Mongoose sea el cliente que sea (Android, iOS, etc.). La fecha se debe enviar en string desde el cliente y, parsear esa fecha a objeto `Date` en orden de guardarlo **en un campo Date** del modelo. Éste es un problema enteramente de diseño.

Aquí lo que te queda hacer es iterar todas los documentos con `status: 1` y, por cada documento comprobar las fechas. Para ésto te puedes apoyar en [moment](https://npmjs.com/package/moment) como ya lo haces.

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  let now = moment();
  let hour = moment().hours();

  Activity
    .find({ status: 1})
    .then((docs) => {
      let activities = []; // actividades que coinciden

      docs.forEach((doc) => {
        let docDate = moment(doc.date);
        if (now > docDate && hour > doc.hour) {
          activities.push(doc);
        }
      });

      // ya tenemos las actividades superiores a X fecha ya Y hora
      activities.forEach((activity) => {
        activity.status = 2;
        activity.save().then(() => {});
      });

      // todo resuelto, podemos retornar las
      // actividades si lo deseamos
      resolve(activities);
    });
});
```

Sí, es mucho más código pero funciona igual que lo ideado.